# Exporting Mesh files from blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I currently have a .mesh file that consists of a fully rigged model, textures and the model itself that I can open in Blender thanks to an XPS importer addon, but I now wish to export this to a format that I can open with other programs.

Unfortunately it seems like no matter what format I try to export it to, something always ends up missing, be it textures or the rigging for the model itself.

Is there any way this model can be exported without losing all the data?

Answer (score 0):

The format you should use depends on what your "other programs" can open and work with.

Blender can export as:

- Collada .dae
- .obj
- Alembic .abc
- .3ds
- .fbx
- .x3d
- .stl
- .ply

None of them contain everything you want. You can export your model as a .obj, your animations as a .fbx and the textures are just image files, why export them into some other format?